# Fitnesse rootpage parameter

Tags: command-line, fitnesse

I'm trying to run FitNesse within a different directory structure. If the start of FitNesse is something like:

`{Path to fitnesse direcotry}\run.bat -d {path to fitnesse directory} -p 8081`

it will work as expected. That means it will find a subdirectory called FitnesseRoot and within this directory my acceptance test suites.

My idea is to rename the *FitnesseRoot* directory to *myNewDirectory* (for example) and then start fitnesse with:

`{Path to fitnesse direcotry}\run.bat -d {path to fitnesse directory} -r myNewDirectory -p 8081`

And this start don't seem to work. Is this so or is there an error in my second statement?

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you seeing? -r works OK for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During last weekend I had some time to explore the problem in deepth. Basically I hadn't understood the operation procedure of the -r parameter. In the mean time it works also well for my belongs. Sorry for the inconvience.